# Search engine for bicycle rentals

Tags: online-resources, rental, bicycles

Many websites compare car rental prices.

Are there any such websites for bicycle rental?

Answer (score 6):

It certainly exists for the USA:

[RentaBikeNow.com](http://www.rentabikenow.com/) help cyclists find and reserve rental bikes 24/7 Shop, it allows you to compare and reserve items from participating bike shops when it’s convenient for you. Reservations can be made at more than 250 bike shops.

Comment: Downvoted - this sounds way too fluffy to be anything other than an advertisement, and it doesn't really address the OP's problem; you can't compare bike rental prices between different bike rental shops/agencies in the same way as you can with rental cars. It's coverage also seems fairly patchy, to say the least.

Comment: PS - it looks like you may have copied the text verbatim, I'll be happy to remove the downvote if this is made to look less like an advert.

Comment: I found that site already but it just looks like one particular chain, not a site comparing across all bicycle rental places.

Comment: I don't think it is a chain, based on the diversity of bike shops on the site. There is also a page where you can add your bike shop to its database. I agree this reads like an add, but I think it's a sound answer.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Didnt mean it to sound like an advert, have now edited answer accordingly

Comment: @DJClayworth Thx for your comments, if it wasnt a sound answer I wouldnt have bothered in the first place.

Comment: @gerrit Is this answer still worthy of a -1 vote ?

Comment: Downvote removed.

Answer (score 2):

There is also at least one site where you can view listings for bicycle rentals from private citizens (includes prices):

https://www.spinlister.com/